# streamlit multipage: How to import module from different directory

Tags: python, import, python-import, streamlit

I am trying to build a multipage dashboard where each page uses functions written in a separate .py files. `Title_page.py` can read function (called 'add_two()') from `func_1.py` without any problem. However, `Page2.py` can't seem to read function (called 'multiply_two()') from `func_2.py` under `p2_functions folder`, which is placed inside the **`pages`** folder. It throws an error saying:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p2_functions'

I think it's because streamlit ignore anything other than .py files inside the **`pages`** folder, but I don't know how then I could call modules and read functions from other .py files or from other folders.

Here's what I have in the Page2.py:

```
import streamlit as st
from p2_functions.func_2 import multiply_two

st.markdown("# Page 2 ")
st.write(multiply_two(10 * 20))
```

Here's the tree of the structure:

```
├── Title_page.py
├── func_1.py
└── pages
    ├── Page2.py
    └── p2_functions
        └── func_2.py
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pages.p2_functions.func_2 import multiply_two
```

Imports in Streamlit always work relative to the directory where you run streamlit run ..., so in your case the root of your directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the `p2_functions` folder path into `Page2.py` if they are from different folders.
E,g

```py
import sys
# Insert functions path into working dir if they are not in the same working dir
sys.path.insert(1, "C:/<p2_functions folder path>/") # Edit <p2_functions folder path> and put path

from func_2 import multiply_two
```

That is the way streamlit can recognise other files from other paths